# facing issues while running python testcases using fixtures

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

i want to test my main python code which has one class and few methods like below

```
class SampleClass:
     def sampleconnect(self):
        ## method to connect returns cursor from:
        return self.connection.cusor
```

Now in my testing code how will i call fixture and return instance of class and connection cursor
i tried below but not working"

```
import pytest

#c1 = None

#cur=None
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def db():
    print("In the SetUp")
    c1 = connect_to_s3.SampleClass()
    db = c1.sampleconnect()
    yield db
    print("Cleaning")
    db.close()

class MyTestCase:
    def test_connect(db):
        connect_to_s3.SampleClass.samplemethod(db)
```

on running the test case its not recognizing db as an cursor returned from fixture. Also how can i return class instance and cursor both into my class method which i want to test.

Answer (score 0):

[fixture example](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html)

This is very good example similar to your case

2 possible mistakes in your code:

`def test_connect(db):` should have be `def test_connect(self, db):` inside a class

`def sampleconnect(self):` has no parameters, while `connect_to_s3.SampleClass.samplemethod(db)` does, not sure it is static or class method?!

Here is a good example copied and pasted from the link.

```
# content of test_db_transact.py

import pytest


class DB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.intransaction = []

    def begin(self, name):
        self.intransaction.append(name)

    def rollback(self):
       self.intransaction.pop()


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def db():
    return DB()


class TestClass:
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def transact(self, request, db):
        db.begin(request.function.__name__)
        yield
        db.rollback()

    def test_method1(self, db):
        assert db.intransaction == ["test_method1"]

    def test_method2(self, db):
       assert db.intransaction == ["test_method2"]
```